# Let's abort the [updates]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

The [updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/updates) tag has the following description:

> [Instead of using this tag, please use the appropriate tag for the software and/or library in question] Updates can refer to the modification of data or configuration by an application, process, or service, or can refer to the modification of software by a process. This tag seems fairly useless, as most software engages in updating something most of the time.

This tag is useless and this is stated in its description. It has been added to 3,589 questions at the time of posting, which spans topics from app store updates to database transactions.

I think the [updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/updates) tag should be burninated and replaced with tags that provide useful information, for example [database-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-update) (which already exists but has no usage guidance).

The [updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/updates) tag meets all 4 criteria for burnination:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   No. Whilst all these questions are vaguely about "updates", based on questions currently with this tag, [updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/updates) could be referring to operating system updates (software upgrades) or database updates (database transactions) and this tag is hence ambiguous.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   No. I could "update" many things that have absolutely nothing to do with programming, such as the theme of my kitchen.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   No. [updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/updates) could mean anything and is hence worthless, whereas [database-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-update) gives my important information about the context of the question.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   No, since there aren't any common contexts. This tag is simply far too ambiguous.

Comment: It's definitely ambiguous; and it doesn't pass the "Can you become an expert in/ with [updates]?" litmus test either. Probably still wise to go through the actual [burnination criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination/324071#324071) in your post.

Comment: A cursory glance at the newest and highest scored questions, a simple straight up removal is enough in this case.

Comment: @zcoop98 I've added the burnination criteria to my post

Comment: @Braiam Most systems have a way to opt out of updates. And if you cancel an update while it's running, that should not leave stuff inconsistent - sensible update mechanisms are transactional.

Comment: @Bergi can you share a example of such system? I can't even imagine how such thing would work.

Comment: @Braiam There's [Microsoft's TxS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS), and on Linux [SUSE](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP1/html/SLES-all/cha-transactional-updates.html) and [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630261/what-is-meant-by-transactional-updates) support transactional updates using BTRFS snapshots. Same for OS upgrades - they typically leave the old system around as a fallback until the new one is up and running. You can also achieve something similar manually by cloning a folder, doing the update of the copy, then overwrite the original in a single move.